# ##[warning]Directory 'D:\a\1\a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact 'drop'

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts, build-pipeline

I created azure build pipeline for asp.net code using classic build editor, the zip file is not getting published in the drop folder

[choosing asp.net build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdW5f.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIWrb.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t52DW.png)

[warning image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJHAM.png)

Comment: From the screenshot, the VS build step only runs 8s. the project may not be built successfully. If the build does not produce the expected artifacts files, it will fail to publish. Can you share the log of the VSbuild steps? Current information is insufficient for further investigation